# Force a script refresh using the "yepnope" JavaScript script loader

Tags: javascript, yepnope, dynamic-script-loading

Using [yepnope.js](http://yepnopejs.com/). I need to "refresh" the script, but yepnope prevents files with the same url from being re-loaded.

In the documentation, they suggest using a plugin to allow files to refresh.  Is there such a plugin available?  What are my other options for refreshing a script during runtime in Javascript?

I tried appending a random number as a query argument to the url.  That worked, but made it much more difficult to set breakpoints while debugging, so I'd rather not do this.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO it **is not possible** do that using any yepnope method.

I think you only has two possibilities:

- Adding a random parameter to the querystring (your current solution)
- Changing the yepnope script to:

  1. expose the `scriptCache` yepnope var
  2. reset the `scriptCache[url]`
  3. and finally *remove* the created **DOM img node** that has your *url as src*.
  4. In addition set the cache headers to expired, to prevent browser cache.

good luck

Comment: Should I just add the script manually do you think? What is the way do it manually (without the use of yepnope)?

Comment: I thought that your need to reload the script using yepnope.Otherwise, if you can reload it without yepnope logic, use this: 
`var s = document.createElement('script'); s.src = url; document.getElementByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);`